# loading xml content failed using Qt

Tags: xml, qt

I have written below simple code to read xml.
but setting content itself is failing for me.

I am using Visual studio 2010 and Qt 4.8.5 lib.

```
QDomDocument document;
QFile file(str);

if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    cout << "Failed to open file";
} 
else 
{
    if(!document.setContent(&file)) // here my sample code is failing and going inside this 
    {
       cout << "Failed to load document"; 
    } 
}
file.close();
```

Comment: You can pass a `QString*` to [`QDomDocument::setContent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdomdocument.html#setContent-7) to get an error message. You can get the line number and column too.

Answer (score 1):

If setContent is failing, then it is likely that the XML is not valid. You can check the XML with a validator, such as [this one](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/).